# How do we find domain, co-domain and range?

Tags: calculus, functions

Often a function (real, say) is written without mentioning its domain, co-domain, just the rule $y=f(x)$ is given. In that case, how does one determine the domain, co-domain and range? For example, consider $f(x)=1/x$.

Comment: this function maps R to R. therefore R is the codomain, but R is not the domain -- we have values such as x=0 that aren't in the domain. we know that the range doesn't include 0 either. the range is a subset of the codomain

Comment: $x$ cannot be ___ because otherwise $y= \frac 1x$ would be undefined... For all other $x\in \mathbb R, \; \frac 1x $ is defined.  So what is the domain of the function?  Please edit your post to include some of your own work on this.

Answer (score 3):

The practice of not stating the domain and co-domain is a bad practice.

A function is only well defined only when the domain, co-domain and the rules are given. They should be pre-specified in order to define the function. The range are the values in the codomain that has a preimage. Codomain can be anything that contains the range as a subset.

However, for most examination based question, what they intend to ask is what is the largest possible subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that can be used as the domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate domain it is usually problem with even root or with denominator.

Say you have $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and

a) $f(x) = {x+3\over x-2}$, then $D_f = R\setminus \{2\}$

b) $f(x) = \sqrt[4]{x-6}$, then $D_f = [6,\infty)$.

The hard part is range. For the first example. Lets see if $2$ in range. Then you have to find such $x$ that $f(x)=2$, so you must solve the equation:

$$ {x+3\over x-2}=2$$
which is solvable ($x=7$) and thus $2$ is in range. But you can't really do that for each number directly. You must solve more general equation. Take $a$ any and see for which one is equation $f(x)=a$ solvable. So we have:
$$ {x+3\over x-2} =a\;\; \Longrightarrow \;\;  x= {2a+3\over a-1}$$
and thus it is solvable iff $a\ne 1$ so the range is $\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$

Actually, if you are familyar  with the inverse function, searching for range is actually searching a domain for the inverse function.